# Trying to produce correct recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Didn't know who to ask at this time of night. But I'm trying to implement recursion for the first time with not much background knowledge. I am getting some result on the right track but the program is now in an infinite loop.

```
def url_open(url, count, position):
  for i in range(count):
     newURL = 0
     html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
     tags = soup.find_all("a")
     newURL = dict_populate(tags, position) 
     url_open(newURL, count - 1, position) 

def dict_populate(tags, position):
  workingCOUNT = 0
  workingDICT = {}
  newURL = 0 
  for tag in tags:
     workingCOUNT += 1 
     for key,value in tag.attrs.items():
        workingDICT[workingCOUNT] = value 
     new = workingDICT[position] 
     return new

url = input("Enter - ")
var1 = input("Enter count - ")
var2 = input("Enter position - ") 
searchCOUNT = int(var1)
urlPOSI = int(var2)
url_open(url, searchCOUNT, urlPOSI) 
print("The last url retrieved: ", url)
```

It works with low values of *count* 1, 2, 3, but over that it gets into an infinite loop.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I have posted the whole program.

This program parses webpage for a URL. The website that I'm asked to use is a website that contains links to other websites of the same links but in different order. I need to find the url in position n and that repeat the process for n other websites until I find the last one.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?  Please explain what does code do. You are using Recursion inside a for loop.

Comment: Please share some input/output expected, and a reproducible example, here we don't know what `dict_populate` is

Comment: Consider using return.

Comment: You are not actually entering an infinite loop. Since with every for loop, you are again calling the function, it is just a long loop until you get a recursion error

Comment: Yep the program returned a result after some time. First time I went to go get food waiting for a program to finish! I thought that recursion is to call itself again again thus being a loop itself? Here the condition for termination would be the for loop with x - 1... which I thought would terminate when x = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `while` statement.
`While` Loops is used to execute a block of statements repeatedly until a given condition is satisfied.

[image]

```
# assign a default value to a variable called "count" 
count = 0
# iterate until test expression is False
while (count < 5): 
   count += 1; 
   # print results
   print("count is :" + str(count) )
```

Output:

```
count is :1
count is :2
count is :3
count is :4
count is :5
```

Obviously, you can manage `while` statements inside a `for loop`.

```
for item in my_items_list:    
       while some_conditions:
           # do something here
```